# Dual OLED displays showing the same image via SPI?

Tags: arduino-uno, u8glib

Is it possible to connect two oled displays via SPI to my Uno and send a single image to both displays, with each refreshing at an identical rate?

I have gotten a single oled display (SSD1306) to work using the U8g2 library, however i am not sure which pins can be shared in a dual display setup. There are no CS pin on my displays, only GND, VCC, SCL, SDA, D/C, and RST.

thanks!

Comment: Those displays use I2C, not SPI.

Comment: Here is a link to the displays I purchased: http://www.ebay.com/itm/141494092860?ul_noapp=true

I have a single screen running using the 4 Wire SPI bus setup in the U8g2 lib, is that possible if the displays are I2C? I'm new to this, so honest question...

Comment: My bad. The labeling made me think it was I2C, but apparently it support both I2C and SPI. Since in 4 wire SPI, you can only write to the display, and not read, I don't see why you shouldn't be able to connect two displays. Just connect all six lines in parallel.